# IIS 8 URL Redirect on site level

Tags: windows-server-2012, redirect, iis-6, 301-redirect, iis-8

I am trying to do a simple 301 perm redirect to another url in IIS 8. The end results would be if i navigated to domain2.com i would end up on domain1.com.

We are moving from IIS 6 to a new server and have aprox 600+ sites that will be configured on this IIS 8 box.  All of these sites run a proprietary CMS and are looking at the same directory for source code. 
In IIS 6 i would just go to the Home directory tab of each site and check the box that says "Permanent Redirect" and provide a URL.  With IIS 8 there is "HTTP Redirect" and this looks like it would do the trick but it is being applied to all the sites in IIS 8 that share the same source code directory. Not on the site level like it use to be in IIS 6.  I also looked into URL Rewriting module for IIS 8 but it seems to take rules in the style of a firewall and i am not sure if i could effectively create rules that would cater to 600+ sites.

I am looking for the easiest way to have redirects on my site level so that that customers with multiple domains can have there sites redirect to there main domain for seo purposes. I feel like this was so easily achieved in IIS 6 that i must be overlooking something in the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution. I am not sure if this is the best way to accomplish this but to get around this had to create a unique directory and a separate site in IIS 8. I configure the redirects for that site and since it is pointing at unique directory the settings do not carry across to  other sites in IIS 8.